# Include a function & JSX in Conditionally Rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How Can I conditionally render a JSX along with a function in React Native. I want to hide and show loading conditionally.

```
return (
  state.isLoading ? showLoader(true) :
  showLoader(false)
  (
    <View>
      ...
    </View>
  )
)
```

the showLoader function is added to the component from another context.

```
const { showLoader } = useContext(LoaderContext);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve with it:

```js
render() {
  const { showLoader } = useContext(LoaderContext);

  return (
    <View>
      { this.state.isLoading ? showLoader(true) : showLoader(false) }
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it by doing something like this:

```
return (
  <View>
    {state.isLoading ?
      showLoader(true) :
      <>
        {showLoader(false)}Insert Content Here
      </> 
    }
  </View>
)
```

You're question lacks a bit of clarity, if you can provide more information I can give a more precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional rendering in React works the same way conditions work in JavaScript. Here, we can compare it with if else condition, if isLoading is true (state.isLaoding?) it will show the loader (showLoader(true)) else it will show the view(...).

```
return (
      state.isLoading ? showLoader(true) :
      (
        <View>
          ...
        </View>
      )
    )
```